# Snake to Camel Case: [SOLVED] I'm stuck in the second string, when i concatenate can't skip the first char, to don't repeat de char[0]

Tags: javascript, dictionary, methods

The function only can solved with .map, i cant find the way to skip the first index of each string to solve the excercise.

`

```
let snakeToCamel = function(string) {
    // Your code here
    const result = string.split("_").map(char => char[0].toUpperCase() + char.toLowerCase());
    return result.join("");
};
console.log(snakeToCamel('snakes_go_hiss')); // 'SnakesGoHiss'
console.log(snakeToCamel('say_hello_world')); // 'SayHelloWorld'
```

`

This is my best trie, i google for answers but i dont find nothing with .map method, if anyone know where are my error i been so grateful. Thanks!

PD: I can't use .replace!

I SOLVED, REPLACING THE "... + char.toLowerCase()" to "char.substring(1).toLowerCase()"

Answer (score 0):

Rather than index specifiers `[]`, I would use slice for this..

`char.slice(0,1)` get first char,  `char.slice(1)`, get chars from index 1 to end..

eg.

```js
let snakeToCamel = function(string) {
    const result = string.split("_").map(char => char.slice(0,1).toUpperCase() + char.slice(1).toLowerCase());
    return result.join("");
};
console.log(snakeToCamel('snakes_go_hiss')); // 'SnakesGoHiss'
console.log(snakeToCamel('say_hello_world')); // 'SayHelloWorld'
```

Comment: OH! Thanks its a good way to solve it, I try that solution!